Do we need a visa for a layover at Singapore?
If we are travelling to Bali(Indonesia) via Singapore, do we need a visa in this situation?
I have added the flight details as an example to know if visa(Singapore) would be needed in this situation?


Hard to answer without knowing your nationality.

@StuartF in Singapore people staying airside do not need a visa, whatever their citizenship.

As long as you buy these flights as a single booking, you don’t need a visa to transit through Singapore.
The situation would be different if the flights were ticketed separately (self-transfer), or with some low-cost carriers, but not in the case of Singapore airlines.
